# Pointing consumer to proper input when declaring a custom router?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

First time using the custom router function which would act as a filter as mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_filtering) and I was wondering, who do I redirect the input to?

In the past I had only the consumer which is declared as follows:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<MyClass<T>>> myFunction() {
    return ...;
}
```

Together with the properties set as:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        myFunction-in-0: "input"
        input:
          destination: "my-kinesis"
          binder: kinesis
          group: "my-group"
```

But now, having a custom router declared, I'm confused if that is still the proper input as `myFunction-in-0`.

The custom router function returns the following `FunctionRoutingResult`:

```
            return new MessageRoutingCallback.FunctionRoutingResult(
                    myCondition ? "myFunction" : "devNull"
            );
```

Also, added the `devNull` sink for cases where the condition is not met.

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<MyClass<?>>> devNull() {
        return ...;
    }
```

**EDIT**: the error thrown is as follows:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myfunction-in-0' to org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingProperties:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingProperties]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

`spring-cloud-stream` version: `3.2.4`

`spring-boot-starter-parent` version: `2.6.6`

`spring-cloud-dependencies` version: `2021.0.3`

Could it be the generics in the received message? Can it be automatically parsed into the POJO?

Comment: What exactly is the signature of `public Consumer<Message<MyClass<T>>> myFunction() `? I am really curious as to why is it thinking that it is converting String to BindingProperties. Best thing you can do is provide a small sample that reproduces the issue and push i to github somewhere so we can tale a look quickly

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky will do! In here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pulls?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky just got it fixed by wrapping all `binder, destination, etc` properties right after the `functionRouter-in-0` config clause, instead of ref the `input` name. Probably not valid when using routing functions and only when having a single function?